# How to construct acceptable phrasal verbs

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Native speakers using Phrasal Verbs very frequently, because it can express a lot of meanings.

but

Is there any rule that I can follow to construct **acceptable** phrasal verbs?

Comment: What do you mean by "construct"? Do you want to "invent/create" new phrasal verbs? There are no rules for learning how to USE phrasal verbs if that is what you mean.

Comment: Do you want to **"invent/create" new phrasal verbs**?
Yes

Comment: There are no rules, people can invent new words and expressions whenever they like, but whether other speakers will understand, recognize, remember or use these expressions/phrasal verbs is something entirely different. E.g. If I say "Can you **see up** a word in the dictionary?" you might well understand its meaning but the fixed expression is **look up**, and it is the one you should use in everyday conversation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't, they evolve from normal uses of verbs with prepositions or adverbs becoming more specialised or generalised in use until they acquire a meaning that isn't quite the same as before and are then learn the same way that individual words are learnt.

*Run into* in the sense of "encounter" started as a metaphor of actually running and this running bringing the subject into something. It's only with the metaphor becoming a dead metaphor where we no longer think as much of the imagery the metaphor had been using that it became a phrasal verb.

It wasn't constructed **as** a phrasal verb, and we learn its meaning the same way we learn the meaning of a word.